# Is there a freely available, no restrictions listing of public companies (US or otherwise)?

Tags: finance, companies

I am wondering if there is a freely available dataset of publicly traded companies (US or otherwise) with **zero restrictions** on use of said data? (A site like [OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/info/our-data/) does **not** meet the conditions of my question, as it seems you have to pay for a license, depending on how you use the data.)

A [Wall Street Journal article from 2017](https://www.wsj.com/articles/where-have-all-the-public-companies-gone-1510869125) says there are 3,671 public companies in the US.

Comment: You might contact the exchanges directly and ask, though it's possible they don't allow open use of the symbols either.

Comment: I have a list.  Also have a question though: Do you want this to include updates as well as all historical listings?